# Hash Tables seg fault

Tags: c++

So I'm really not sure what is causing the seg fault but I have a feeling that it has something to do with hashTables since the debugger shows it seg faults right at this line its involved with.

Here is the code that is causing the seg fault

```
//Constructor for hashtable
HashTable::HashTable()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        hashTable[i] = new Movie;
        hashTable[i]->title = "empty";
        hashTable[i]->year = 0;
        hashTable[i]->next = NULL;
    }
}

//destructor for hashtable
HashTable::~HashTable()
{

}

// this will take a string and convert the letters to hash numbers then add them all together and divide by the hash table size to get a index
int HashTable::initHash(std::string in_title)
{
    int hashT = 0;
    int index = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < in_title.length(); i++)
    {
        hashT = hashT + (int)in_title[i];
        std::cout << "hash = " << hashT << std::endl;
    }

    index = hashT % 10;
    std::cout << "index = " << index << std::endl;

    return index;
}

//This is where we will be inserting a new Movie into the hashtable, 
//it will first use initHash to find the number of where it should go in the hash and then from there add it to the hashtable
void HashTable::insertMovie(std::string in_title, int year)
{
    int index = initHash(in_title);
    std::cout << "index = " << index << std::endl;

    if (hashTable[index]->title == "empty") // *** seg faults right here ***
    {
        hashTable[index]->title = in_title;
        hashTable[index]->year = year;
    }

    else
    {
        Movie* Ptr = hashTable[index];
        Movie* n = new Movie;
        n->title = in_title;
        n->year = year;
        n->next = NULL;
        while(Ptr->next != NULL)
        {
            Ptr = Ptr->next;
        }
        Ptr->next = n;
    }
}
```

in each of my functions containing hashTables[index] it seg faults but I'm not exactly sure why, the index comes back with a number that should work. does anyone know why this would happen?

edit: Ok here is the two classes that matter from my header file

```
struct Movie{
    std::string title;
    int year;
    Movie *next;

    Movie(){};

    Movie(std::string in_title, int in_year)
    {
        title = in_title;
        year = in_year;
    }

};

class HashTable
{
    public:
        HashTable();
        ~HashTable();
        void insertMovie(std::string in_title, int year);
        int initHash(std::string in_title);
        int NumberofItemsInIndex(int index);
        Movie* findMovie(std::string in_title/*, int *index*/);
        void deleteMovie(std::string in_title);
        void printInventory();
        void PrintItemsInIndex(int index);
    protected:
    private:
        Movie **hashTable;
};
```

edit 2: Here is the main() function

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // Declarations
    int input; // Declaring an input for the menu
    bool quit = false; // Bool for the menu
    //string title; // input value for certain actions
    //int year; // input value for certain actions

    HashTable *ht;
    //int index;

    //readFileIntoHash(ht, argv[1]);



    while(quit != true)
    {
        displayMenu(); // Displays the main menu
        cin >> input;

        //clear out cin
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10000, '\n');

        switch (input)
        {

        // Insert a movie
        case 1:
            {
                string in_title;
                int year;
                cout << "Enter Title:" << endl;
                cin >> in_title;
                cout << "Enter Year:" << endl;
                cin >> year;
                ht -> insertMovie(in_title, year);
                break;
            }

        // Delete a movie
        case 2:
            {
                string in_title2;
                cout << "Enter Title:" << endl;
                cin >> in_title2;
                ht -> deleteMovie(in_title2);
                break;
            }

        // Find a movie
        case 3:
            {
                string in_title3;
                cout << "Enter Title:" << endl;
                cin >> in_title3;
                ht -> findMovie(in_title3);
                break;
            }

        // Print table contents
        case 4:
            ht -> printInventory();
            break;

        case 5:
            cout << "Goodbye!" << endl;
            quit = true;
            break;

            // invalid input
        default:
            cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void displayMenu()
{
    cout << "======Main Menu=====" << endl;
    cout << "1. Insert movie" << endl;
    cout << "2. Delete movie" << endl;
    cout << "3. Find movie" << endl;
    cout << "4. Print table contents" << endl;
    cout << "5. Quit" << endl;
    return;
}
```

I added displayMenu() for clarity's sake.

Comment: Actually I don't see any memory allocations for `hashTable`. You have to allocate memory for your `hashTable` before trying to store something there.

Comment: @tema:
`hashTable` you mean?

Comment: Could you post the `class` declaration of hash table?

Comment: yeah I'll post my header file

Comment: Another comment: segmentation faults are not guaranteed to appear even though an illegal read/write operation has occurred. It may crash at any time after or not crash at all, hence even though you think it's at a certain line, the error may be somewhere else.

Comment: Change `Movie **hashTable` to `Movie *hashTable[10]` in the header file

Comment: @jsantander I gave that a shot but it still seg faulted at the same location.

Comment: @tema I tried putting hashTable = new Movie*[10] at the start of the constructor since I figured that would be how I allocate memory for it but it didn't seem to do anything, just to clarify that is the right way to allocate memory right?

Comment: @Mike , it will be good if you can provide us a code where you're trying to create `HashTable`

Comment: I second what tema and Betamos said. Given what you said you had attempted, it might be that the problem is in the allocation of your HashTable instance. The code you have shown is certainly wrong, but it might be the case that there's an additional problem elsewhere in code you have not shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the class definition:

```
class HashTable
{
    public:
        HashTable();
        ~HashTable();
        void insertMovie(std::string in_title, int year);
        int initHash(std::string in_title);
        int NumberofItemsInIndex(int index);
        Movie* findMovie(std::string in_title/*, int *index*/);
        void deleteMovie(std::string in_title);
        void printInventory();
        void PrintItemsInIndex(int index);
    protected:
    private:
        Movie *hashTable[10]; /*<<-- since your size is fixed use an array*/
};
```

Also.. since you allocated Movies in the constructor, remember to deallocate them on destructor:

```
//destructor for hashtable
HashTable::~HashTable()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        delete hashTable[i];
    }
}
```

Alternative, use dynamically allocated memory (with your same class definition)

```
HashTable::HashTable()
{
    hashTable = new (Movie*) [10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        hashTable[i] = new Movie;
        hashTable[i]->title = "empty";
        hashTable[i]->year = 0;
        hashTable[i]->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

and

```
HashTable::~HashTable()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        delete hashTable[i];
    }
    delete[] hashTable;
}
```

---

Additional fix:

modify main function:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // Declarations
    int input; // Declaring an input for the menu
    bool quit = false; // Bool for the menu
    //string title; // input value for certain actions
    //int year; // input value for certain actions

    HashTable ht; // <<==== local variable, not a pointer!
```

... and then replace `ht->xxxx(...)` for `ht.xxxx(...)` elsewhere.

Comment: I do agree that I need to allocate memory for my hashTable so I went ahead and added that to my code. I am still getting a seg fault to maybe its something else in the rest of my code that is causing the issue.

Comment: I tried debugging one of my other functions and it seems that the hashTable problem is no longer there and its seg faulting elsewhere now. So this solution did help, I only need to find why it doesn't like it when I work with the string 'title'. Thank you.

Comment: @Mike.... after you posted your `main()` it is clear that the problem is that you didn't allocate the HashTable instance.... either use new (and delete at the end)... or use a plain variable instead of a pointer.

Comment: Ah! There we go, that did fix the only warning I had and now everything seems to be working fine, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`hashTable[i] = new Movie;` there you allocate memory for Movie

but memory for `Movie **hashTable;` was not alllocated

try to add `hashTable = new Movie *[100];` to constructor

Answer (score 0):

This constructor perhaps:

```
HashTable::HashTable()
{
    hashTable = new (Movie*) [10]; // Allocate memory on the heap for the array
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        hashTable[i] = new Movie;
        hashTable[i]->title = "empty";
        hashTable[i]->year = 0;
        hashTable[i]->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

<strike>However, there is actually no need have an array of `Movie` pointers in your hashmap, you could simply have an array of `Movie` objects instead.</strike> Actually, you want a linked list so my bad. Also, I would not write `10` everywhere, rather use a constant so you could change the size later.

When you get this to work, *you should write a destructor* to avoid memory leaks. Hint: couple each call to `new` with a call to `delete` (and `new[]` with `delete[]`).

Comment: Yeah I gave that a shot but it still seems to seg fault at the same line.

Comment: @Mike can you post your `main()` function?

Comment: Oh, actually now the program depends on user input instead, so it's still not too easy to debug. E.g. `deleteMovie()` isn't shown. What input gives you the segmentation violation?

Comment: It seems the problem was in an warning I was getting in main. I declared the HashTable class as a pointer and not a variable which was causing seg fault issues later on. Once I fixed that it went back to working fine. Thank you for your help!